# spring boot unable to generate tables in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to update the data base schema from defiend JpaEntities but spring boot is not able to generate the database tables.
Log file:

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banque_db
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

client entity class:

```
 @Entity(name="client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long code;
private String name;
private String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "compte")
private Collection<Compte> comptes;
// + getters and setters
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.0.RELEASE
         
    
    com.Tuto

```
<artifactId>MaBanque</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MaBanque</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually, the issue was the entity classes were not in the right package.
  org.example that contains the main class and org.entities
for some reason spring boot did not generate the tables so when i moved the entity package to become like org.example.entities and run the app , all the tables where successfully generated.
thank you guys for help I appriciate :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create` for db creation or `create-drop`

See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: 
The `application.properties` file:

1. If you set attribute `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`, it will not create the schema for you. Instead, it will, you know, **update** the existing database, which you currently does not have.
2. The **default** value for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`  is `create-drop` but you are overriding it.
3. Your application.properties **must** be in

> src/main/resources

folder.

==> you should fix to:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create - drop

Second problem: The entity class. You should add **@Column** on top of the attributes, like so:

```
`@Entity(name="client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long code;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "compte")
private Collection<Compte> comptes;
// + getters and setters`
```

Answer (score 0):

@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.acme.model"})  // force scan JPA entities
public class Application

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).